# How can I make a union of mongoose queries in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here's my current code:

```
Model.containing(req.user.location, function(err, models) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.render('models/index', {title: 'Models', models: models});
});
```

I get a list of models that contain the user's location.  It works great.  Now I want to get all of those previous models and one extra.  I could retrieve this extra model with something like:

```
Model.find().where('name').equals('desired name').exec(function(err, models) {
 //got my models!
});
```

Could I combine them to do something like this?

```
Model.containing(req.user.location, function(err, models) {
  if (err) throw err;
  Model.find().where('name').equals('desired name').exec(function(err, newModels) {
    var allModels = models + newModels;
    res.render('models/index', {title: 'Models', models: allModels});
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Almost, but since `models` and `newModels` are arrays you need to call `concat` to merge them instead of using `+`:

```
var allModels = models.concat(newModels);
```